# How to prove a probability inequality in Feller's book?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1, X_2$ be independent real-valued random variables with their tail distributions satifying $1-F_i(x)\sim x^{-\rho}L_i(x)$, where $\rho>0$ and $L_i(x), i=1,2$ are slowly varying functions. Let $t'=(1+\delta)t>0, \delta>0, t>0$. For every $\varepsilon>0$ and $t$ large enough,
$$P(X_1+X_2>t)\geqslant (1-\varepsilon)[P(X_1>t')+P(X_2>t')].$$
How to prove this inequality?

Remark 1. Let $L(x)$ be a positive monotone function on $[0, \infty)$ to $[0, \infty)$. We say $L(x)$ be slowly varying at $+\infty$ if $L(tx)/L(x)\to 1$ as $x\to \infty$ for every $t>0$.

Remark 2. This inequality comes from W. Feller. An Introduction to Probability Theory and
Its Applications. Wiley & Sons, 1971, page 279, (8.15).

Comment: There must be something missing here, for example if $X_2=0$ and $P(X_1 > t') > 0$ then is it impossible.

Comment: @copper.hat I have added the conditions of the distributions of the two r.v.'s according to Feller's book.

Comment: You might elaborate what slowly varying means.

Comment: @copper.hat I have given the defination of slowly varying function in Remark 1.

Comment: Not sure I understand why this was closed?

Comment: @copper.hat I find out that, in Feller's book, one important condition "independency" has been added in his "proof". So, the original inequality is very simple, but the detailed proof of (8.15), in Feller's book, is not simple yet. Fortunately, I have proved this conclusion. Thank you for discussing this question with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days of thinking, I finally came up with the answer to this question.

Firstly, we must understand the following properties:

Property 1.  If $P(C_n)\to 1$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$ and $n$ large enough,
$$P(D\cup C_n)\geqslant 1-\varepsilon\geqslant P(D)(1-\varepsilon).$$

Property 2. (i) $A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$.

(ii) $A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$.

Property 3.  Since $\{X_1>t', X_2>-\delta t\}\subset \{X_1+X_2>t\}$ and
$\{X_2>t', X_1>-\delta t\}\subset \{X_1+X_2>t\}$, so
$$\{X_1+X_2>t\}\supset \{X_1>t', X_2>-\delta t\}\cup \{X_2>t', X_1>-\delta t\}.$$

Secondly, we start to prove the inequality we wanted.

Proof. Define
$$A=\{X_1>t'\}, B=\{ X_2>-\delta t\},$$
$$ C=\{X_2>t'\}, D=\{ X_1>-\delta t\}.$$
Note that
$$A\cup D=D, B\cup C=B, B\cup D=\{X_1>-\delta t\}\cup\{X_2>-\delta t\},$$
and
$$(A\cap B)\cup (C\cap D)=(A\cup C)\cap (A\cup D)\cap(B\cup C)\cap (B\cup D).$$
It's easy to see that, as $t\to \infty$,
$$P(A\cup D)=P(D)\to 1, P(B\cup C)=P(B)\to 1, P(B\cup D)\to 1.$$
From the Property 3, 2 and 1 we can get that
$$P(X_1+X_2>t)\geqslant P(A\cap C)(1-\varepsilon).$$
Now the inequality we wanted follows from the independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$, that is
$$P(X_1+X_2>t)\geqslant [P(X_1>t')+P(X_2>t')](1-\varepsilon).$$